# Minimum Requirements for Azure SharePoint Development VM

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio, visual-web-part, azure

I'm interested in developing SharePoint Visual Web Parts in Visual Studio but don't have an instance of SharePoint Server running anywhere. Visual Studio points me to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/set-up-a-general-development-environment-for-sharepoint) page, which suggests a Microsoft Azure VM.

My question is what is the minimum specs I need to run a SharePoint server and Visual Studio for development? Prices vary widely:

[image]

Comment: And remember you can de-allocate the VM when it's not in use so the actual expense could be a somewhat less than the published monthly estimate. If you use it 40 hours a week all month you're going to pay about a quarter of that estimate (provided you remember to de-allocate it every time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The D4S_V3 would what I would consider the minimum specifications for a development VM.